# Почему вызов dismiss в onCreate в DialogFragment выполняется после onCreateView?

Tags: android

У меня есть фрагмент (выложил самое нужное):

```
public class MyFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    ...
    ...
    ...

    public MyFragment(RecyclerView.Adapter adapter, Context context) {

        ...
        ...
        ...

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);

        if (my_action == ACTION_DELETE) {

            ...
            ...
            ...

            dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_work_with_dictionaries, null);
        (view.findViewById(R.id.work_with_dictionaries_button_1)).setOnClickListener(this);
        editText_1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.work_with_dictionaries_editText_1);

        ...
        ...
        ...

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       ...
       ...
       ...

       dismiss();
    }

       ...
       ...
       ...

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);

        editText_1.setText("");
    }
}
```

В `onCreate`, при выполнении условия, я вызываю `dismiss()`, а за ним должен вызываться `onDismiss`, в котором я очищаю `EditText`. Но проблема вот в чем — `EditText` инициализируется в `onCreateView`, который, по смыслу, после `dismiss()`, вызываться не должен, а значит и `.setText()` — должен выдавать NPE! Но оно почему-то работает! Так почему же?

Comment: А вы уверены, что onCreateView не вызывается перед исполнением onDismiss?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, неа. Но на экране ничего не появляется.

Comment: Это не значит, что метод не вызывается... Если вы в начале методов  жизненного цикла и в методе onDissmiss() поставите `System.out.println("НАЗВАНИЕ МЕТОДА");` то в каком порядке и какие методы выведутся в консоль?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну да... Сначала `onCreateView`..

Comment: Ну, видать асинхронно вызывается се метод. По крайней мере в сорцах в комментах так написано: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/support-v4/r7/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.java#DialogFragment.onDismiss%28android.content.DialogInterface%29

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, в ответ закиньте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видать асинхронно вызывается сей метод. По крайней мере в [сорцах](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/support-v4/r7/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.java#DialogFragment.onDismiss%28android.content.DialogInterface%29) в комментах так написано:

> ...dialog dispatches this asynchronously so we can receive the call after the activity is paused.  Worst case, when the user comes back to the activity they see the dialog again.